# Where to store script files for cronjobs?

Tags: php, linux, unix, cron

In which diretory should script files for cronjobs be saved? Available to the public inside `var/www/html` or better inside `var/www/files` or ...?

Comment: Why would you want to make cronjob script files available to the public? If you're distributing them, `var/www/*` would be a fine place to put them. If you're intending to run them on your server, put them somewhere that isn't public facing, like your `/home` directory

Comment: Wasn't sure if the crontab needs the script files to be stored in a public directory. If I don't have access to the `home` directory but only to `var/www/*`, which directory would you recommend? Only `var/www/html`is public, isn't it?

Comment: Cron only needs its scripts to be in a directory it can access. As for publicity, it depends on your configuration. If you're running Apache as your web-server, then accessibility of any directory under the web root (usually, and likely in this case, `var/www`) is configured by `.htaccess` files. By default, all sub-directories and files are accessible. If you don't care about other people seeing your cron scripts, go ahead and put it in `var/www`. Otherwise, put them somewhere else or change your server configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-posting comments from above, for easier reference and clarity:

Why would you want to make cronjob script files available to the public? If you're distributing them, `var/www/*` would be a fine place to put them. If you're intending to run them on your server, put them somewhere that isn't public facing, like your `/home` directory

Cron only needs its scripts to be in a directory it can access. While it can definitely access `/var/www/`, so can (potentially) the public; it depends on your configuration. If you're running Apache as your web-server, then accessibility of any directory under the web root (usually, and likely in this case, `/var/www`) is configured by `.htaccess` files (or in a `Directory` block in your main server config). By default, all sub-directories and files are accessible. If you don't care about other people seeing your cron scripts, go ahead and put it in `var/www`. Otherwise, put them somewhere else or change your server configuration

Answer (score -2):

The best way to do that you want, is create a new directory dedicated to save the scripts, for example, /var/www/html/scripts
In that way, people is able to see the the sctipts and for crontab schedule too.

Comment: The public shouldn't be able to see the scripts!